# want to know the working of fractions part in the code.I am beginner.Please give me clear explanation

Tags: pyspark, databricks

how fractions work here

I tried changing values after ":" .still was not able to get how it works?

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

dataset = sqlContext.range(0, 100).select((col("id") % 3).alias("key"))
sampled = dataset.sampleBy("key", fractions={0: 0.1, 1: 0.2}, seed=0)
sampled.groupBy("key").count().orderBy("key").show()
```

No error messages

Answer (score 0):

[sampleBy](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy) and [sample](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample) use internally [Bernoulli sampling](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/bernoulli-sampling/) to take the sample. All members of your dataset have an equal, but independent chance to become part of the result. The fractions represent this chance. You will often get strange results with small datasets and maybe think that it isn't an useful function, but due to the [weak law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) of large numbers the probabilities converge to the expected value for large datasets. Spark is made for large datasets.